# Why for-of-loop has not finished running, jump out to run console.log?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, console.log, node-inspector

### Runtime environment

- Visual Studio Code v1.15.1 own compiler
- Node.js v8.2.1
- OS: Windows 10

### Description

I want to add "After sort:" between source arry and sort arry, look like this:
[image: CONSOLE Screenshot 1]

But console occasionally shows:
[image: CONSOLE Screenshot 2]

Why for-of-loop  has not finished running, jump out to run console.log ? Source code:

```
// Random to generate double digits.
function getRandom() {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
}
// Writing data to the array.
var score = [
  ["a", getRandom()],
  ["b", getRandom()],
  ["c", getRandom()],
  ["d", getRandom()],
  ["e", getRandom()]
];
console.log("Before sort:");

// Print source arry
for (let m of score) {
  console.log(m);
}

// Call sort()
score.sort((a, b) => {
  return b[1] - a[1];
});
console.log("After sort:");

// Print sort arry.
for (let n of score) {
  console.log(n);
}
```

Comment: This sure looks like a bug in the inspector.

Comment: yes true, my bad

Comment: So this is a bug of node-inspector  rather than the js code error?

Comment: Yes. Unless you can get the code to output wrongly computed results, this seems to be a problem with the tooling around `console.log`.

Comment: Given the high reproducability and the minimal test case, you probably should report this issue to the developers of Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score -1):

Seems array is not prepared when you try to print due to accessing same method from array property multiple times and the method contains some numerical calculation so surround by timeout

```
// Random to generate double digits.
   function getRandom() {
     return Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
    }
   // Writing data to the array.
   var score = [
   ["a", getRandom()],
   ["b", getRandom()],
   ["c", getRandom()],
   ["d", getRandom()],
   ["e", getRandom()]
  ];
  console.log("Before sort:");
  setTimeout(function(){
      // Print source array
      for (let m in score) {
        console.log(m);
       }

      // Call sort()
     score.sort((a, b) => {
         return b[1] - a[1];
     });
     console.log("After sort:");
     for (let n in score) {
       console.log(n);
     }
  },300);
```

Comment: sort is not external link , its internal library function. its not async.

Comment: Sorry, your code produces the same error.[Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/AYqZm8W.png)

Comment: Array should have homogenized elements only here the array having [string, number]

Comment: "*May be reference issue*" - what do you mean? What does your code do different?

Comment: @RajaMohamed Heterogenous arrays are completely fine in JS.

Comment: suspect 'Math.round(Math.random() * 100)' consuming much of time and didt behave like sync in this place

Comment: `Math` is definitely sync and takes hardly any time.

Comment: I m not blaming math alone.  you cant call and execute same method in same time (millisecond equal ) because methods are not instances, I hope time out will work

Comment: You don't understand my mean . If code like this:

```

var score = [["a", 55], ["b", 33], ["c", 44], ["d", 88], ["e", 22]];


for (let m of score) {
  console.log(m);
}
console.log("After sort：");
```

This bug will still appear: [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/0fUXBNo.png)

Comment: Still I hope settimeout will help you ,if you don't have best option then try with settimeout.

Comment: @Raja Mohamed Thanks, i will try it.